# Multiple pattern grep

Tags: r, regex

I have a file (`tsm`) as below :

```
V1                                                        V2

Library Name:                                            abc

DriveName:                                               123

Device Type:                                              xyz

WWN:              567

Library Name: feg

DriveName:    124

Device Type:    wef

WWN:   312
```

I want to get an output with only the drive name followed by `wwn`.

I have tried , but I get a `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` message.

> ```
> > tsm[grep("DriveName | WWN",tsm$V1,fixed = TRUE) , ]
> [1] V1 V2
> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> ```

Comment: What is the expected output?  If you need the rows with either DriveName or WWN Try `grep("^(DriveName|WWN)", tsm$V1)`

Comment: How about removing the space in `"DriveName | WWN"` or the argument `fixed = TRUE`?

Comment: yes removing the space and fixed =true also worked , thanks !

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
tsm[grep("^(DriveName|WWN)", tsm$V1),]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the solution, thanks for the assistance !

```
tsm[grep(c("WWN|DriveName"),tsm$V1), ]
```